# Categories visible only After login and Logout?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, product-list

I just played around with an already built Magento application. The client had added the products from admin panel and it was not visible on in website.

I referred to the theme documentation and it said that the category tree that was currently implemented in the application was wrong. So I made the necessary changes to expect the categories to be visible but no luck. After playing more I just signed up and logged in to the website and could see the respective Categories in the header during login and even after logout.

I didn't understand what happened here. After clearing cache of browser and visiting the site again, the categories disappeared. I want the categories to appear on the website even without user registration and login/logout. How can I implement this task?

Comment: He ( My manager :) )

Comment: share in detail what changes you have done,  and before you check these points: The products must be Visible in Catalog.
The products must be Enabled.
Product must have a stock Quantity.
The product must be set to In Stock.
If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
The product must be assigned to the target Category.
If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

First you spend an hour trying to check these points:

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock.
- If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
- You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

**Second :**

Also check your magento database table "customer_group" for customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN . customer_group_id for customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN must be 0.

```
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN'
```

Comment: HI Surya, Yes I have checked all the parameters that you have mentioned. But when a new user tries to visit categories aren't displayed unless he/she registers and logs in

Comment: share your category admin screenshot. also tell me if you have added any new extension in magento

Comment: Also check your magento database table "customer_group" for customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN . customer_group_id for customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN must be 0 .     UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code = 'NOT LOGGED IN'